# Category Filter is not showing up for when products from only one category are there in Magento 2 project. [Need help]

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Okay so I am using [Amasty Shopby Brands](https://amasty.com/shop-by-brand-for-magento-2.html) extension and have separate brand pages where product listing is shown. There is also layered navigation on the left side. However, it doesn't show the Category Filter in the layered navigation when there are products from only one category. We would like for it to show the category filter even that case.

I looked into the code and found a plugin which I think is responsible for bringing in the category filter on the brands page. It was coded by another fellow developer in the team.

It looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\Catalog\Plugin;

use Amasty\ShopbyBrand\Controller\Index\Index;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;

class Brand
{
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_categoryCollection;


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param CollectionFactory $categoryCollection
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $categoryCollection
    )
    {

        $this->_categoryCollection = $categoryCollection;
    }

    /**
     * Set default category filter
     *
     * @param Index $subject
     * @return null
     */
    public function beforeExecute(
        Index $subject
    ){
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollection->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
        $categoryId = null;
        foreach ($collection as $index => $menuItem) {
            
            if ($menuItem['name'] == "All Categories") {
                $categoryId = $menuItem['entity_id'];
            }
        }
        $params = $subject->getRequest()->getParams();

        if($categoryId && !array_key_exists('cat',$params)){
            $subject->getRequest()->setParam('cat', $categoryId);
        }
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

It seems like it brings the Category filter and selects 'All Category' as the active filtering, which is the parent category of all categories in our magento 2 project.

Based on my analysis of this plugin's code, it seems like the selection of 'Active Filter' is getting applied whenever there is no query in the search such as

`<domain_name>.com/<brand_name>?cat=9973`

and only works when it looks more like this:

`<domain_name>.com/<brand_name>`

The main issue that I am currently facing is that the category filter in layered navigation is only showing up for when there are products from more than one category in the brands page. If there are products from only one catgory in that particular brand page(which is very common in this project) then only the Active Filtering shows up which selects the 'All Category' Category however it doesn't show the corresponding category whose products are on that particular brand page.

How can I modify the code such that the category filter shows up when there are products from one category.
Or is there a way to modify the approach to bringing in the category filter on the brands page?

**Images for reference:**

**Screenshot of layered navigation of a brand page where there are products from only one category:**
https://i.imgur.com/ppnNXER.png

**Screenshot of layered navigation of a brand page where there are products from more than one category:**
https://i.imgur.com/7EG8jwu.png

*PS: I have run all the standard commands in developer mode such as setup upgrade, di compile, reindexer, static content deploy and cache flush.*